# How do I solve $dv/dt=ov^2+a$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

How do I solve $\cfrac{dv}{dt}=ov^2+a$?

Here, $a$ is the acceleration from gravity, $v$ is the speed, $t$ is the time and $o$ is a constant.

I am trying to make a formula for quadratic drag but it seems that integrating both sides doesn't work since $v$ appears on both sides.

Comment: I think it would help if you wrote a few words identifying your variables, i.e., $v$, $o$, and $a$;  At least that would make sure people don't mix up $o$ and zero!  Anyway, I take it you mean $a$ to be acceleration from non-frictive sources, such as gravity.  Wouid I be right?  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

It is a separable ODE

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t} = kv^{2} + a \Longleftrightarrow \int\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{kv^{2} + a} = \int\mathrm{d}t
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the ode as follows,

$$\frac{dv}{\rho v^2+a} = dt$$

which can be integrated as

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{a\rho}} \tan^{-1} \left( \sqrt{\frac{\rho}{a}}v\right) = t + C$$